# Removing randomness from program execution

Tags: system-call, entropy

So I have a program which is highly obfuscated and generates a unique output every time. For ease of reversing I want to make it so that the output is the same for every run (following the logic that if the output is the same, the logic executed will be the same, roughly..)

At one point `strace` shows that the program does a number of calls to `clock_gettime` just before it generates an id. So I created a kernel module that makes `clock_gettime` return exactly the same time. Yet the program is still able to produce a unique output.

In my opinion all programs must make system calls to get unique entropy for seeding random functions and without making any system calls (or if all system calls they did make were made to return non-unique entropy) the program can't produce unique (random) data.

Are there any ways I'm missing that the program can get unique entropy without showing up on `strace` (i.e. without making a system call)?

Comment: Can you please upload the program?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible in this case. Though I'm looking for a technique I can apply to any program anyway.

Comment: Does it read from something like /dev/rand ?

Comment: `rt_sigaction` is the only other syscall called before generating the id. No file opens.

Comment: In addition if it is Intel processor reseed and rdrand instructions may be used, it does not require system call.

Comment: The code runs both on AMD and Intel architectures. Though that does sound promising and I haven't checked if its still random on AMD after `clock_gettime` interception.

Comment: Besides clock, there may be other variable parameters in the system which can very well serve as seed, e.g. processor % utilization, amount of memory used, processor usage of top five processes etc. Any arbitrary combination of one or more of these can serve as a week seed to random number generator.

Comment: Some program (eg OpenSSH) are known to read uninitialized memory cells from the stack to augment entropy (remember the problem on OpenSSH key generation on Debian systems).

Comment: btw, there is also rdtsc instruction.

Comment: You may want to give Mozilla rr a try on it. It records system calls and other sources of randomness/nondeterminism and allows you to replay it in gdb (including stepping backward and forward). If the overhead of whole-system execution is OK, then you may want to look into PANDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes, there are a lot of ways to generate entropy without system calls (this can be weak entropy, but anyway).

Here is a small (but obviously not even close to pretend to be full) list:

- rdrand, rdseed instructions from intel random generator(btw, supported by AMD since 2015).
- rdtsc instruction - which gives you a tick count since power up
- uninitialized memory
- internal program addresses generated as a result of ASLR